# JSON deserialization into C# class hierarchy

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm getting JSON from a web hook where the type of the object is baked into the JSON itself, kind of like this:

Example of data that is of type "a":

```
{
    "type": "a",
    "name": "object name",
    "a_data": "something specific to type a"
}
```

And Example of data that is of type "b":

```
{
    "type": "b",
    "name": "another object name",
    "b_data": {
        "b_field1": "Something specific to type b",
        "b_field2": "Something else specific to type b"
    }
```

I am guaranteed that every payload will have a `type` and a `name` property.  All payloads of `type` "a" will additionally have an `a_data` property, and all payloads of `type` b will additionally have a `b_data` property, itself made up of properties `b_field1` and `b_field2`.

(Of course this very simplified to illustrate this question - the real use case has much longer and more complex json and many more types)

I would want to deserialize into C# classes, modeling a base class (containing at least the `name` property and possibly the `type` property), and two derived classes, one for those objects that are serialized in `type` "a" json, and one for those objects serialized in `type` "b" json.

I would imagine defining C# classes like:

```
    public class Base
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class DeriviedA: Base
    {
        public string a_data { get; set; }
    }

    public class DervivedB : Base
    {
        public class DataB
        {
            public string b_field1 { get; set; }
            public string b_field2 { get; set; }
        }

        public DataB b_data { get; set; }
    }
```

Given that I don't know when a payload is incoming what type it is, I'll need to deserialize conditionally based on the the incoming type.  But I don't "know" what type that is until I deserialize.  I'm pretty sure the following would work, but it is not a particularly good solution, because it means I need to deserialize twice:

```
        public static Base Deserialize(string incomingJson)
        {
            Base tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Base>(incomingJson);
            switch (tmp.type)
            {
                case "a":
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DerivedA>(incomingJson);
                case "b":
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DerivedB>(incomingJson);
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"unable to deserialize payload of type {tmp.type}");
            }
        }
```

Now aside from needing to do the ungraceful double-deserialization, note that I would NOT be able to mark the `Base` class as `abstract`, even though I never want an instantiation of the `Base` class by itself.

Anyway, I am curious about ideas or strategies or best practices for doing this.  My *preference* would be to use Newtonsoft for the deserialization, but it isn't a *requirement*.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a non-deserializing JSON reader to sniff the type before using a serializer.

Newtonsoft has a really easy way to do this:

```
dynamic message = JObject.Parse(json);
string type = message.type;
```

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm